Why is "getMeUser" returning user as null on payloadcms?
I'm running into an error accessing the "/checkout" page using "www.example.com" but it works on "example.com".
The user is being returned as null probably because here, I'm fetching the user from "example.com".
const meUserReq = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/users/me`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
    },
  })

Shouldn't "www.example.com "also work since I have included it on cors & csrf?
I tried adding "www.example.com" as a second URL like so, but it didn't work.
 const meUserReq = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/users/me` && "https://www.example.com", {
   headers: {
     Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
   },
 })


CSRF only applies to cookie-based tokens. If you want, instead of attaching a JWT, you can "include" your token along with your fetch request if you a cookie is present on your frontend.
You also need to include the content-type in your request as per the Payload docs - https://payloadcms.com/docs/rest-api/overview
try {
  const req = await fetch('{process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/users/me', {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
  const data = await req.json()
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}


